# Concise way to expose View's JButtons objects to Presenter

Tags: java, private, mvp, inner-classes, code-completion

I'm writing a GUI app in Java using the MVP design pattern.  `JButton` objects belong in the View class and the `ActionListener` objects belong in the Presenter. I'm looking for a concise way to allow the Presenter to add `ActionListener`s to the View's `JButtons` without either (1) making the buttons `public` and (2) without having to add a bunch of methods to the view that look like

```
private JButton foo;
private JButton bar;

public void addActionListenerToButtonFoo(ActionListener l) {
  foo.addActionListener(l);
}

public void addActionListenerToButtonBar(ActionListener l) {
  bar.addActionListener(l);
}

// (imagine typing 10 more of these trivial functions and having 
//  them clutter up your code)
```

I found one technique that works reasonably well:

```
public class View {

  class WrappedJButton {
    private JButton b;

    public WrappedJButton(String name){
      this.b = new JButton(name);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
      b.addActionListener(l);
    }
  }

  public final WrappedJButton next = new WrappedJButton("Next");
  public final WrappedJButton prev = new WrappedJButton("Previous");

  public void setup() {
   JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
   buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   buttons.add(previous.b);
   buttons.add(next.b);
 }
} // end view

class Presenter {

  public Presenter() {
    View view = new View();

    view.next.addActionListener(event -> {
      // Respond to button push
    });
  }
} // end Presenter
```

This wrapper works well.  Making the wrapped buttons `public` allows the Presenter to reference them by name (which allows my IDE to use code completion); but, because they are `WrappedJButton` objects, the only thing the Presenter can do is add an ActionListener.  The View can get "full" access to the objects by grabbing the "real" button through the private `b` field.

Questions:

1. Is there an even better/cleaner solution? Perhaps something that
   would eliminate the need to access the `b` field in the View?
2. Is there a way to generalize this solution so I don't have to
       cut-and-paste `WrappedJButton` into every View class I write?  I
       tried moving `WrappedJButton` into an interface (which View
       implements); but, when I do that, View no longer has access to the
       private `b` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be ok to avoid copy-pasting the `WrapperJButton` class by exposing the wrapped buttons on the package level (assuming the the `Presenter` resides in a different package):

```
public class WrappedJButton {
    final JButton b;

    WrappedJButton(String name){
      this.b = new JButton(name);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
      b.addActionListener(l);
    }
}
```

A different approach could be to store the buttons in a map:

```
class ButtonMap<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final EnumMap<E, JButton> map;

    ButtonMap(Class<E> buttonEnum){
        map = new EnumMap<>(buttonEnum);
        for(E e : buttonEnum.getEnumConstants()){
            map.put(e, new JButton(e.toString()));
        }
    }

    JButton get(E e){
        return map.get(e);
    }

}
```

a view using this map could look like this:

```
public class View {

    private final ButtonMap<ViewButton> buttonMap = new ButtonMap<>(ViewButton.class);  
    public enum ViewButton{
        NEXT("Next"), 
        PREV("Prev");

        private final String name;

        private ViewButton(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return name;
        }
    }  

    public void setup() {
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(buttonMap.get(ViewButton.PREV));
        buttons.add(buttonMap.get(ViewButton.NEXT));
    }  

    public void addActionListener(ViewButton button, ActionListener l){
        buttonMap.get(button).addActionListener(l);
    }

} // end view
```

The button map is hidden with a private field. Only the `addActionListener` method of the buttons is exposed.